# Line with key word $(this) doesn't work when button is clicked - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var undoButton = $('<input type="button" id="undoBtn" value="UndoSelection">').addClass('button');
        $(windowContainer).append(undoButton);
        $(undoButton).click(function(){
            var seat = $('<img/>',{src:'gfx/seat.png'});
            var seatYellow = $('<img/>',{src:'gfx/seat_yellow.png'});
            if(($('td').hasClass('p')) && ($('td').hasClass('picked'))){  
                **$(this).html(seatYellow);**                                   
            } else if (($('td').hasClass('n')) && ($('td').hasClass('picked'))){
                **$(this).html(seat);**
            }

        })
```

Lines `$(this).html(seatYellow)` and `$(this).html(seat)` don't work. When I repleace word `(this)` by `('td')` the first part of if statement will work what is obvious, because it returns true. However it's not what I want. I want particular td elements to be replaced by `seat` or `seatYellow`, and that's why I use `(this)`.For some reason it doesn't work. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `this` will refer to `<input type=button ...>` inside the `$(undoButton).click` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(windowContainer).on('click', undoButton, function() {
```

or this way:

```
$(windowContainer).on('click', '.button', function() {
```

or `delegate the event to document`:

```
$(document).on('click', undoButton, function() {
```

or this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
```

Comment: Doesn't `on` take a selector as a parameter and **not** a jQuery object?

Comment: I have tried your solution but it removes everything. I need to try something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ofcourse `.html()` does that. If you want to append in the current div data then use `.append()` instead `.html()`.

Comment: and use `.prepend()` if you want to prepend data at first index of the div container.

Answer (score 0):

Think about where do you want to apply the html with the image data to. At the moment you are trying to add the image into the input tag with value undoButton.

You need to remember a reference to the element you would like to add the seat to.

```
var el = $(this);
var undoButton = $('<input type="button" id="undoBtn" value="UndoSelection">').addClass('button');
$(windowContainer).append(undoButton);
$(undoButton).click(function(){
    var seat = $('<img/>',{src:'gfx/seat.png'});
    var seatYellow = $('<img/>',{src:'gfx/seat_yellow.png'});

    if(($('td').hasClass('p')) && ($('td').hasClass('picked'))){  
        el.html(seatYellow);                                 
    } else if (($('td').hasClass('n')) && ($('td').hasClass('picked'))){
        el.html(seat);
    }
});
```

It might be better to just apply a class to the current seat and set the image as a background image depending on it being a normal or a yellow seat.